# Python: Making a function signature with inspect

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble figuring out how I should be building a signature manually. The docs say that the `parameters` argument of `inspect.Signature` should be an `OrderedDict`. But that fails for me.

Even the `parameters` in an `inspect.Signature` instance, returned by the `inspect.signature` function don't play well as an `__init__` argument:

```py
>>> from inspect import Signature, signature
>>> def f(a, b: int, c=0, d: float=0.0): ...
...
>>> Signature(signature(f).parameters)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/twhalen/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 2775, in __init__
    kind = param.kind
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'kind'
```

But `Signature(signature(f).parameters.values())` works fine. Yet `type(signature(f).parameters.values())` tells me it's an `odict_values`, not an `OrderedDict` as the docs say.

How **should** one construct a `parameters` argument for `inspect.Signature`?

Is the misalignment between `inspect`'s documentation and the truth of the code just that, or is there some profound reason I'm missing?

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something important (but not very profound). The documentation for the [class attribute `parameters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.parameters) reads

> An ordered mapping of parameters’ names to the corresponding [`Parameter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter) objects. Parameters appear in strict definition order, including keyword-only parameters.

However this the output of the class initializer. The documentation for the `__init__` argument `parameters` reads:

> The optional *parameters* argument is a sequence of [`Parameter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter) objects, which is validated to check that there are no parameters with duplicate names, and that the parameters are in the right order, i.e. positional-only first, then positional-or-keyword, and that parameters with defaults follow parameters without defaults.

The input is expected to be a sequence, not a mapping. The output is an ordered mapping in the [`Signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature) object. The `Signature` class is really not meant to be initialized "by hand" unless you have a special case where you need to.

The type `odict_values` represents the result of a call to `OrderedDict.values`. It is a sequence, which is why that particular call works. You can print the ordered dictionary to get a better sense of what's happening:

```
>>> signature(f).parameters
mappingproxy(OrderedDict([('a', <Parameter "a">), ('b', <Parameter "b: int">), ('c', <Parameter "c=0">), ('d', <Parameter "d: float = 0.0">)]))
```

You can ignore the [`mappingproxy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType): it just makes the whole thing read-only. `Signature`'s initializer does not need the mapping because `Parameter` objects already contain the name of the parameter.

Comment: I had it all, except for the crucial  _parameters argument is a sequence_. In that case, okay, documentation is not lying, but still, why this misalignment of signature's attribute and argument (both carrying the same "parameters" name)?

Comment: @thorwhalen. Why not? Besides renaming either the attribute or the parameter, I don't really see a problem, especially given that the class is usually meant to be generated by the `signature` function, not through its constructor.

Comment: "Why not" hardly seems a good design principle. On the other hand "Same name. Same type. Same thing" does seem to me like a good guideline since it minimizes surprise and facilitates remembering what's what. That said, I'm guessing I won't get the rationale (if there is any) of this choice unless I ask the author. You answered the first question, so I'll accept yours as the answer.

Comment: @thorwhalen. You can absolutely contact the original authors: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/inspect.py#L31